# Is It possible to a rebuild Index with out taking instance offline?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this one `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` that's 85.71% total fragmentation and 55.35% page fullness.

Can this be done without taking my instance offline and not enterprise edition?

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Rebuild failed for Index 'idx_last_success_download'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.2500.0+((KJ_PCU_Main).110617-0038+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Rebuild+Index&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.50.2500&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1222&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

After Reorganized:

```
ALTER INDEX idx_last_success_download ON dbo.TERMINAL_SYNCH_STATS 
REORGANIZE;
```

I'm still getting 85.71 fragmentation?

Using for my stats: [DBCC SHOWCONTIG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008.aspx)

```
DBCC SHOWCONTIG scanning 'TERMINAL_SYNCH_STATS' table...
Table: 'TERMINAL_SYNCH_STATS' (331148225); index ID: 38, database ID: 7
LEAF level scan performed.
- Pages Scanned................................: 7
- Extents Scanned..............................: 5
- Extent Switches..............................: 6
- Avg. Pages per Extent........................: 1.4
- Scan Density [Best Count:Actual Count].......: 14.29% [1:7]
- Logical Scan Fragmentation ..................: 85.71%
- Extent Scan Fragmentation ...................: 40.00%
- Avg. Bytes Free per Page.....................: 3613.9
- Avg. Page Density (full).....................: 55.35%
```

Comment: Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175008(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Then my answer did defragment

Answer (score 0):

Lock time out is not a version issue

Yes it is *possible* to rebuild an index online.
You have a lock timeout.  I suspect it is an active table and rebuild simply cannot acquire a lock.

Try a Reorganize

[Reorganize and Rebuild Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...I'm still getting 85.71 fragmentation

Comment: WOW, I don't know what to say.  What is your fill factor?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run rebuild with specifying option `WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY` 
e.g. as below

```
ALTER INDEX idx_last_success_download ON dbo.TERMINAL_SYNCH_STATS
REBUILD WITH 
(    FILLFACTOR = 80, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON,
     ONLINE = ON (WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY
         (MAX_DURATION = 4 MINUTES, ABORT_AFTER_WAIT = BLOCKERS ) ),
     DATA_COMPRESSION = ROW
);
```

For more info refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx

Comment: You did not asked version of SQL Server and so your answer becomes totaly incorrect if user is having any version less that SQL Server 2014. I can see it is tagged SQL Server 2005 so your answer is incorrect because WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY option was introduced in SQL server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Please note in any case you dont have to take `SQL server database or SQL Server instance offline` to rebuild any index. Yes if you have Standard edition ONLINE index rebuild is not possible and you have to make sure application or some query is not accessing the table otherwise index rebuild would fail

What is output of

```
select @@Version
```

The erorr message

> Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

Only says that when index rebuild task was trying to get exlcusive lock on table, because during index rebuild index is dropped and recreated , it was not able to get hence the error message. It is not a threatening message. You can get this message both in standard and enterprise edition while rebuilding index.

Index rebuild is maintenance activity so should always be done when load on database is relatively very less or during mainteance window.

For solution try rebuilding when no body is accessing database or laod is very less

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: You have standard edition so you cannot have online index rebuild. You would have to make sure table is not accessed when index rebuild is going on so rebuild index during application downtime preferably